# Prove that honeycomb structures are the most geometrically efficient structure

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

I was reading [this paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb) and it got me thinking:

> The closed ends of the honeycomb cells
>   are also an example of geometric
>   efficiency, albeit three-dimensional
>   and little-noticed. The ends are
>   trihedral (i.e., composed of three
>   planes) sections of rhombic
>   dodecahedra, with the dihedral angles
>   of all adjacent surfaces measuring
>   $120^o$, the angle that minimizes surface
>   area for a given volume. (The angle
>   formed by the edges at the pyramidal
>   apex is approximately $109^\circ 28^\prime 16^{\prime\prime}$ $\left(=
> 180^\circ - \cos^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)\right)$

This is hardly intuitive; is there a proof of this somewhere?

Comment: i remember reading somewhere that the bees didnt use the best possible (but very close and optimized wrt some other variable).

Comment: Nice video from PBS Infinite Series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8jOxEGVyPo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to divide space up into uniform volume cells with minimum surface area, the honeycomb is not optimal. Look at the [Weaire–Phelan structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaire%E2%80%93Phelan_structure). While honeycombs are not quite optimal, they are certainly close enough for bees -- they're suboptimal by only 0.3%.

Answer (score 2):

It is called geometrically efficient because it is  [**densely packed**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html).

Also read:

1. [Sphere Packing Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing)

Answer (score 1):

This question can be explained and understood with the aid of 
the **physics** of soap bubbles. :=)

One problem when thinking on such questions is that one 
often thinks the walls as "rubber sheets". For the surface 
(and in arbtrary cross sections ways) minimisation the surface 
tension has to be thought constant.

So always when three lamellae join in a common "corner" 
the orthogonal cross section is 120 degrees. (thee identical 
forces in one point) Excuse this "corner" and orthogonal,
I am not aware of geometry in English.